# How to reset the auto incremented id column to 1 whenever I seed the database in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, supabase, supabase-database

I am using Supabase as a backend which provides postgres as its database and prisma for my next-js app. I wanted to seed some dummy data into the database. The first time I run the seed script, everything's fine but when I ran the script multiple times, even though I deleted all rows before seeding, the primary id (which auto increments by default) of the table is not resetting to 1. Instead, it is incrementing from the previous value. I tried something like this:

```
await prisma.user.deleteMany();
await prisma.post.deleteMany();
await prisma.$queryRaw`ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq RESTART WITH 1`;
await prisma.$queryRaw`ALTER SEQUENCE post_id_seq RESTART WITH 1`;
```

This is error occurred when I run raw SQL code in prisma:

```
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `42P01`. Message: `relation "user_id_seq" does not exist`
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/home/surya/projects/social-media-demo/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:29909:13)
    at RequestHandler.request (/home/surya/projects/social-media-demo/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:29892:12)
    at async Proxy._request (/home/surya/projects/social-media-demo/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:30864:16) {
  code: 'P2010',
  clientVersion: '4.3.1',
  meta: { code: '42P01', message: 'relation "user_id_seq" does not exist' }
}
```

Is deleting all the tables and running migrations again as a fresh start the only way?

Comment: `truncate table post reset identity`?  To find out the name of the underlying sequence of an `identity` (or the outdated `serial`) column, use `pg_get_serial_sequence()`

Comment: Do you have a sequence called `user_id_seq`? Does the `ALTER SEQUENCE` statement work when you run it from a SQL tool?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this, it will delete the data and restart the sequence:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <tableName> RESTART IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Supabase database, you can set the desired value for the sequence via `setval`:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.<your_table>_<your_column>_seq', <last_used_value>, true);
```

e.g.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.user_id_seq', 0, true);
```

---

But that error

> `relation "user_id_seq" does not exist`

makes me think that you either are using the wrong sequence name or that you aren't using an autoincrement (hence no sequence created).

- Ensure you are using the correct sequence name, finding it via

```
SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

- If you still can't find it, then check *when* the `seed.sql` kicks in; maybe that's before Prisma did its things on the schema.
  I unfortunately have no experience with Prisma.